# I wanted my input box to accept pattern like txt.txt.txt if its char and 11.22.33.44.55

Tags: html, regex

I am looking for regular expression which should fullfill my below condition

Condition1 - If its character set then its should restrict to three dots only like

xyx.fff.gsd   should display error if it have more than three dots

Condition2 - But if its with digits then it should not restrict the limit

1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8 so on

Currently I am using ^([0-9A-Za-z_-]+.[0-9A-Za-z_-]+.[0-9A-Za-z_]+)$ RegEx but its fulfilling my Condition1 only not 2

Can anyone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow.

Since you put the HTML tag, I guess you want to use JavaScript for your regular expression.

To build a regular expression, a good start would be to identify exactly what you want to match, if possible without examples.

If I understand you correctly, you want your regex to match those 2 cases :

- exactly 3 groups of exactly 3 letters, each separated by a dot
- multiple groups of numbers with a dot between them

Now that this is established, you can start building your regular expression.

I think something like this might fit :

```
^((\d+(\.\d+){2,})|([\w\d_-]+(\.[\w\d_-]+){2}))$
```

You can test it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UZyp9m/8)

**Edit :** Changed the regex according to the comments below

Comment: In first case it should have  three dots only ..no restriction of letters  and for second case as well no restriction of digits and dots

Comment: 3 dots or 3 groups of letters ?

Comment: I edited my answer with 3 groups of letters (total of 2 dots)

Comment: Examples  condition1. {n no of letters and digits combination}.{n no of letters and digits combination}.{n no of letters and digits combination}       Condition2. {n no of digits}.{n no of digits}.{n no of digits}...so on

Comment: Ah first case can contain letter and digits, okay. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I edited the regex, it should match your cases.

Comment: One more thing I missed to mention Condition1 and 2 set can allow to enter_ and - in character set

Comment: Regex edited. Do not forget to accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Yup I will do.. not allowing to add - and _ in condition2

Comment: I inverted the two cases in my regex. When the string contains only digits, the `-` and `_` caracters are not allowed, unless there are 3 groups, in which case it will match your first case.

Comment: Not working for 11.22.33.44

Comment: My bad, I used the wrong quantifiers for that case. Fixed now.

Comment: 111.222 it's showing right..minimum dots should be 2 in both conditions and max 2 for condition 1 and no max for condition 2

Comment: also its not allowing - and _ in condition 2   example are 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1-0
xYx.fT45.g-_jg
xyx.fff.hhh   
1-1.222.333.444.555
1_23.444.8999.99
11.22.33.44.55   these should be valid

Comment: All those rules should have been in your question. We should not have to guess those. This is the reason your question was downvoted. Regex updated.

Comment: `1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.1-0` This sould not be valid. You told me before that "when the string contains only digits, the - and _ caracters are not [allowed]".

Comment: Its working now  Thanks..I will accept this